# Confine jquery if statement to respective divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple jquery plugin that I am calling on two different divs. The plugin includes an if statement and the results are being applied to both divs instead of the actual div the user interacted with. Here is my plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.selectBox = function () {
        $(this).find('.ms-section-select li:first-child').addClass('ms-checked');


        function get() {
            $('.ms-section-select li').click(function (event) {

                $(this).siblings('.ms-section-select li').removeClass('ms-checked');
                $(this).addClass('ms-checked');


                if ($('.ms-new-select').hasClass('ms-checked')) {
                    $('.new-box').show();
                    $('.used-box, .all-box').hide();
                }

                if ($('.ms-used-select').hasClass('ms-checked')) {
                    $('.used-box').show();
                    $('.new-box, .all-box').hide();
                }

                if ($('.ms-all-select').hasClass('ms-checked')) {
                    $('.all-box').show();
                    $('.used-box, .new-box').hide();
                }

            });
        }

        return this.each(get);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the jsfiddle with the html/css/js http://jsfiddle.net/977hv/16/

I tried using $(this).find(...), $(this).next(...), and several other solutions in the if statement but I can't figure out how to separate the two divs from each other.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/977hv/17/

Comment: Let me see if I understand. (this) can't be used inside of an if statement but a variable can be so you just assigned this to the variable "that" and you use "that" in the if statement?

Comment: No, inside of `$('.ms-section-select li').click(function (event) {`, the variable `this` refers to the `.ms-section-select li` element.  We need the original `this` element, so we name it something else, and then use it.

Comment: Ohh ok I see, thanks. If you want to add that in as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "losing" your original reference to `this`:

```
function ($) {
  $.fn.selectBox = function () {
    $(this).find('.ms-section-select li:first-child').addClass('ms-checked');
    var that = this; //save your this to a different variable, that

    function get() {
        $('.ms-section-select li').click(function (event) {
            //this is now the .ms-section-select li element
            $(this).siblings('.ms-section-select li').removeClass('ms-checked');
            $(this).addClass('ms-checked');

            //but we can still use that
            if ($(that).find('.ms-new-select').hasClass('ms-checked')) {
```

jsfiddle.net/977hv/17

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference current jquery instance. Take a look at fixed version:

```
$.fn.selectBox = function () {

    // Current box reference 
    var $this = $(this);

    $(this).find('.ms-section-select li:first-child').addClass('ms-checked');

    function get() {
        $('.ms-section-select li', this).click(function (event) {

            $(this).siblings('.ms-section-select li').removeClass('ms-checked');
            $(this).addClass('ms-checked');

            if ($('.ms-new-select', $this).hasClass('ms-checked')) {
                $('.new-box', $this).show();
                $('.used-box, .all-box', $this).hide();
            }

            if ($('.ms-used-select', $this).hasClass('ms-checked')) {
                $('.used-box', $this).show();
                $('.new-box, .all-box', $this).hide();
            }

            if ($('.ms-all-select', $this).hasClass('ms-checked')) {
                $('.all-box', $this).show();
                $('.used-box, .new-box', $this).hide();
            }

        });
    }

    return this.each(get);
};
```

Then you should search for `.ms-new-select` within current box `$this`:

```
if ($('.ms-new-select', $this).hasClass('ms-checked')) {
    $('.new-box', $this).show();
    $('.used-box, .all-box', $this).hide();
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/977hv/18/